# How to get only Name and login from cmd finger -s

Tags: linux

The cmd finger -s gives output in the format :

```
Login     Name         Tty      Idle  Login Time    Office                   Office Phone
sentman       John Martin   pts/4          Oct  8 13:04 (professional.wp.mvit.in) 41552289
```

I just want the output to be in format

```
Login Name
sentman john Martin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
finger -s | awk '{printf("%s %s\n", $1, $2);}'
```